# How would I be able to make a preloader on a webpage like Squarespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, preloader

Recently I've been thinking about working on a new website layout, but I've come across lots of inspiration lately, but with no luck of finding how to implement them into my project. One of these problems include preloading an image before allowing the webpage the load exactly like how Squarespace presents their website with a preloaded image of their logo and then a quick transition to their webpage. I tried to look at their source code, but with no luck of finding how they did it or what they used (Jquery?/Javascript?). I have no Idea. I did some research, but most of them consist of "progress bars" which I do not want, I would just like to emulate Squarespace with an image and a nice background then transition into my webpage. Would anyone be willing to demonstrate how to do so? Thank you all in advance.

P.S I am still learning JavaScript and Jquery, but I am just fascinated in how people come up with these implementations.

Here is the website link to make things easier: http://www.squarespace.com/ 
You can see at the beginning a logo loads before the whole website loads, that's what my question revolves around.

Comment: Just take the progress bar example and display a logo instead of a progress bar. Help us help you by helping yourself first!

Comment: No, you help me, by showing yourself how to help me first (just kidding bro). I haven't looked into any progress bar, I was just giving an example of what I do not want (a progress bar), but I see what you mean. I'll try that, but in the meanwhile, hopefully someone gives me a good example of how they would approach this. Thank you for the suggestion, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanna try this one?

Tutorial site http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-loading-image-while-page-is.html

## HTML

```
<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

## CSS

```
#dvLoading{
   background:#000 url(images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

## JS

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
       $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
    });
</script>
```